# Convolutional algorithm logic

Tags: c#, image-processing, filtering, emgucv, convolution

Ok, so I am trying to implement my own Convolution alogirthm in EmguCv (it's a requirement). The filtering doesn't seem to work right. The results aren't what is excepted to be. Where would be the error in my algorithm ? Here is what I have done so far:

```
            int L = 3;

            double kernelTopLeft = kernel[0 + L * 0];
            double kernelTopCenter = kernel[1 + L * 0];
            double kernelTopRight = kernel[2 + L * 0];
            double kernelCenterLeft = kernel[0 + L * 1];
            double kernelCenter = kernel[1 + L * 1];
            double kernelCenterRight = kernel[2 + L * 1];
            double kernelBottomLeft = kernel[0 + L * 2];
            double kernelBottomCenter = kernel[1 + L * 2];
            double kernelBottomRight = kernel[2 + L * 2];

                for (int bNumber = 0; bNumber < 3; bNumber++)
                {
                    for (int j = 1; j < img.Width - 1; j++)
                    {
                        for (int i = 1; i < img.Height - 1; i++)
                        {

                           //Getting pixels in 3x3 Window

                            double topLeft = img.Data[(i - 1), (j - 1), bNumber];
                            double centerLeft = img.Data[(i - 1), (j), bNumber];
                            double bottomLeft = img.Data[(i - 1), (j + 1), bNumber];
                            double topCenter = img.Data[(i), (j - 1), bNumber];
                            double center = img.Data[(i), (j), bNumber];
                            double bottomCenter = img.Data[(i), (j + 1), bNumber];
                            double topRight = img.Data[(i + 1), (j - 1), bNumber];
                            double centerRight = img.Data[(i + 1), (j), bNumber];
                            double bottomRight = img.Data[(i + 1), (j + 1), bNumber];

                            //Kernel operation is kernel window * pixel window (multiplication is mirrored)

                            double newValue = bottomRight * kernelTopLeft + bottomCenter * kernelTopCenter + bottomLeft * kernelTopRight +
                                              centerRight * kernelCenterLeft + center * kernelCenter + centerLeft * kernelCenterRight +
                                              topRight * kernelBottomLeft + topCenter * kernelBottomCenter + topLeft * kernelBottomRight;

                            if (newValue > 255)
                            {
                                newValue = 255;
                            }
                            else if (newValue < 0)
                            {
                                newValue = 0;
                            }

                            img.Data[(i), (j), bNumber] = (byte)newValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

My algorithm is practically moving a window of 3x3 across the whole image and multiplying it with the kernel to result the value of the pixel in the middle then it continues until it reaches final.

Comment: Interesting algorithm, yet totally off-topic.. You just pasted a bunch of code and said it doesn't work, with no clues to explained why

Comment: I'm really sorry. I will update the post now. I'm a bit in a hurry and I can't seem to figure out how to debug it.

Comment: You're updating the data in `img` as you go so that the operation on the next 3x3 area will use the new values from `img` for the top-left set of pixels.  Are you sure this is what you intend?  Shouldn't you write the new pixels into a new array so that `img` remains unchanged?  Unless you're doing Error Diffusion or some other operation that requires a carry from one kernel to the next.

Comment: To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution) "The values of a given pixel in the **output** image are calculated by multiplying each kernel value by the corresponding **input** image pixel values." (emphasis mine)

Comment: As for debugging, I'd recommend creating a specific 4x4 image and working out the expected values by hand using old-fashioned pen 'n' paper :P

Comment: Thank you very much Trevor. That is probably the problem. I don't know why I have thought the image must be modified as you move the window

Comment: @DamianRadinoiu If you have any more trouble with this, could you edit the post to include a specific "image", kernel, and the expected output for a small (4x4 maybe) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, it looks like you're calculating the new pixel values then updating the original `img.Data[]` with the new values as you go.  This means that as you progress through the image, each kernel is using the original values for the pixels to the right and in the rows below (which you haven't processed), and using the new values for the pixels to the left of centre and in the rows above (which you have already processed).

For convolution, each kernel should only consider the original values of the image.  To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)#Convolution):

> The values of a given pixel in the **output** image are calculated by multiplying each kernel value by the corresponding **input** image pixel values.

Note that there are some forms of image manipulation where you do carry data from one kernel into the next in some form.  [Error diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_diffusion) such as [Floyd–Steinberg dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Steinberg_dithering) requires the error value for each pixel to be split and added to the pixels that have not yet been processed, but this is typically done by changing the pixels in the input image.

To fix it, create a new "image" of the same size for the output, and update that in the end of the loop instead.

Hope this helps